# Link mulitple divs with a default div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make links to multiple divs. Working fine. But how do I get the show a default div when the page is opened?

```css
.target {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.target>div {
  display: none;
}

.target>div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#home"><span>Home</span></a>
<a href="#team"><span>Team</span></a>
<a href="#contact"><span>Contact</span></a>

<div class="target">

  <div id="home">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

  <div id="team">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

  <div id="contact">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Anyone has a solution for this?

Greetings Nees

Comment: Add an `open` class or something to the one you want to display by default. Pretty simple. If you need to toggle which ones are open and closed - e.g. close one and open another depending on what link you click. You'll need JS.

Comment: `.target > div:target, .target > div:first-child {..` if you want to show the first by default

Comment: Thnx for the info.

Comment: Do you want to use JavaScript